# How to go through extremely long lists of data in java and/or python

Tags: python, list, loops

I've hit a wall in both java and python. I'm using codewars.com to practice coding exercises and in both languages, I can't figure out how to make my code faster. I keep getting timed out when attempting to complete a kata. Here's the problem I'm currently stuck on:

Sum of Pairs
Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.

If there are two or more pairs with the required sum, the pair whose second element has the smallest index is the solution.

Negative numbers and duplicate numbers can and will appear.

NOTE: There will also be lists tested of lengths upwards of 10,000,000 elements. Be sure your code doesn't time out.

Here is my code, which works for the test run but is timed out when attempting the random tests with 10,000,000 elements:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    answer_list = [None] * 2
    lowest = 10000000
    for i in range(len(ints)):
        count = 0
        for j in range(i, len(ints)):    
            count += 1
            if j == (len(ints) - 1):
                break
            if ints[i] + ints[j + 1] == s and count < lowest:
                answer_list[0] = ints[i] 
                answer_list[1] = ints[j + 1]
                lowest = count
    if answer_list == [None, None]:
        return None
    else:
        return answer_list
```

This is my first time writing on Stackoverflow. I'd also like to know if this is the proper format to ask questions. Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: The main problem I see is that you have to traverse the full i * j elements every time, even if you've already found the answer, because you need to be sure you have the answer at the lowest index.  Think about the problem a bit and see if there is a way you can adjust your algorithm slightly to *guarantee* that the first solution you find is the one they are looking for (allowing you to immediately `break`/`return`).

Comment: Consider big-O notation: your algorithm is currently O(n^2), which is why it's breaking because it has to make 10^14 comparisons. There are several things you can do to be more efficient- you could identify only the *distinct* elements, as some are repeated. Consider also if you've done the pair [A, B], you don't need to do [B, A]. Also you want to consider values with smaller indices first- how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it. I should have though about going at it from the second index directly.

Answer (score 0):

the solution they are expecting is probably use a better data structure , use some space to gain time .
this can be done by using a map/a.k.a a dictionary

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    answer_list = [None] * 2
    lowest = 10000000
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(ints)):
        if s - ints[i] in d:
            answer_list[0] = ints[d.get(s - ints[i])]
            answer_list[1] = ints[i]  
            return answer_list
        else:
            d[ints[i]] = i
    return None
```